# Excel 2016 time formatting cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, microsoft-excel-2016

Using Excel 2016, I want to enter 90 minutes as 90:00, or 75 minutes and 33 seconds as 75:33, or 102 minutes and 54 secs as 102:54; then sum the column to report as 268:27.  How do I format the data in cells?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, *strictly speaking,* what you’re asking for is impossible. 
(Or possible but very hard.) 
But you can get the effect you want by applying a custom format of `[h]:mm`:

[image: screenshot of spreadsheet showing requested addition]

This is actually storing the times as

- 90 hours,
- 75 hours and 33 minutes,
- 102 hours and 54 minutes

but the math works out the same. 
In format strings, `h` (or `hh`) means hours *modulo 24*,
which makes sense if you’re also displaying number of days (`d`). 
`[h]` shows total hours, not modulo.

Answer (score -1):

*I don't think that there is any direct method but using little arrangements with Cell Format you can achieve it.*

[image]

**How it works:**

1. Select cell where you want to write time in Minutes.
2. Apply this cell Format to cells: `[m]:ss`.
3. Enter time as usual for example for `90 Minutes` write `01:30 (HH:MM),` for `60 Minutes` `2:00 (HH:MM)` and so on for others.

**Note:**

1. Just to confirm whether Excel is 
   considering them in `Minutes` I've
   applies the `SUM`, you can find the 
   correct conversion in `Hours` in
   `Red color`.
2. Remember, to apply `[MM]:SS` format to 
   the  Formula cell also.